# Can I create a database using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to create a class which uses PDO to interact with MySQL. Can I create a new MySQL table using PDO?

Comment: The title speaks of creating a database, but he question speaks of creating a table. These are two very, very different things.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The `dsn` part, which is the first parameter of the PDO constructor, does not have to have a database name. You can simply use `mysql:host=localhost`. Then, given you have the right privilege, you can use regular SQL commands to create a database and users, etc.

Following is an example from an *install.php* file. It logs in with root, create a database, a user, and grant the user all privilege to the new created database:

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";

    $root = "root";
    $root_password = "rootpass";

    $user = 'newuser';
    $pass = 'newpass';
    $db = "newdb";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);

        $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db`;
                CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                GRANT ALL ON `$db`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';
                FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: @thearchitect Such a good answer and is not accepted? I feel discouraged :(

Comment: Just note that on cPanel hosting plans, you won't be able to see your database except by using phpmyadmin or command line -- it won't show up in cPanel under "MySQL Databases" control panel.

Comment: @JingshaoChen thanks for the helpful answer!  To everyone else, I spent several hours debugging a "create database" query, only to realize that in the "Create Database `$db`" string, those are "backticks" NOT single quotes!!!  You must bracket the name of the new database in BACKTICKS!!  Hopefully this will save someone the annoyance of having to figure out the same thing.

Comment: @Volomike im confused - can i use this if my site has Cpanel? i've tried but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Can we do something similar with Postgres?

Comment: How do you open the new database after you've created it? A new PDO object?

Comment: What is the root user and password here ? its not mysql user id and password right ?

Comment: @logan It is the user that has privilege to create databse, user, and grant privileges to a user. This can be a root.

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution works because it seems to me that CREATE DATABASE requires a db name without quotes. Anyway be careful with sql injection! Imagine that you have the following string in $db: `$db = "newdb; DROP DATABASE olddb;";` (Posted on behalf of [meons](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4944587/meons), who has insufficient rep to comment)

Comment: @PhilipC the name of the database is in back ticks, not quotes.

Comment: @hypervisor666 I used backticks but there's a new problem; database name which comes from user input has unwanted single quotes. I mean after execution of query, i have a new database named **'my_new_db'** instead of **my_new_db** . What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's the same, like running a regular query like "CREATE TABLE ...".

Comment: When creating a PDO connection, you need to associate that connection with a database right? I was wondering if that can be avoided or if it would be dangerous to use the default mysql database or else if it would be best to just create an empty database where PDO can connect to.

Comment: @Haim : What is the root user and password here ? its not mysql user id and password right ?