# php script automatically creating mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

does anyone know if there's a script out there that will create a mysql database automatically instead of having to go into cpanel and create a database, username and password manually?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You cannot create a username and password unless you log in yourself with a user with a higher level. That's usually the root. Creating database is a breeze after using the username and password with sufficient privileges.

```
<?php

    $dsn = $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,"root","");

    //Creation of user "user_name"
    $pdo->query("CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass_word';");
    //Creation of database "new_db"
    $pdo->query("CREATE DATABASE `new_db`;");
    //Adding all privileges on our newly created database
    $pdo->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on `new_db`.* TO 'user_name'@'%';");

?>
```

In this script, I **assumed** your root user is called "root" and its password is ***empty*** if that's not the case, change line 4 to match.

Comment: i think I will already be logged into the server.  I plan to install the script with ftp to my website and server, then i would like to create an install.php page to make it easy to create the database. I might not be explaining things correctly.

Comment: Your script should not create the database (imho), but the user who wishes to install your application should. Take note of all the larger CMSs and applications, they ask **you**, the user, for the database name, username and password. However, if you already have a PDO object opened and connected at the time of running the script, feel free to skip the first 2 lines.

Comment: Cpanel does not allow you to do this

Comment: @Lan: Why should I care about cPanel? The question didn't say anything about cPanel.

Comment: why two variable ? `($dsn = $dsn)`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create new user without logging in.

You can create database with root account or user with privileges

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "gm123") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE cat") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("cat") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE user(username varchar(20), password varchar(20), permission varchar(20))") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username,password,permission) VALUES('gm','311807','admin')") or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE cattbl(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,name VARCHAR(30),roll INT NOT NULL,technology VARCHAR(30),semister VARCHAR(30),shift VARCHAR(30),bdate varchar(30),cell VARCHAR(30),address VARCHAR(30),picture LONGBLOB)") or die(mysql_error());        

        header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

**you  may try this for your problem**

Answer (score 0):

i have just been doing this on my project

the actual answer is you can but it's a little complicated.

Cpanel doesnt allow you to use the normal "CREATE DATABASE 'mydbname';" in a php script to create a new database.

the only way you can do it is via logging on to your cpanel, going through the database wizard and creating a new one. Up until now you have probably been doing this manually each time.

this can been done with a php script but you have to use an api - which kind of goes through those same actions but automatically. You have to give the api your cpanel username and cpanel password.

just follow the answer to this question 
[Create cpanel database through php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989920/create-cpanel-database-through-php-script)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

require_once 'database.php' add this line of code your index.php

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username= 'root';
$password ='';

$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed !" . $conn->connect_error()); 
}
    else
    {
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE test_employee";

        if($conn->query($sql)== TRUE )
        {
            echo "Database Created Successfully";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can! You can use PHP.

First you need to connect to the database.  Then you need to run a SQL query on that database that creates the database.  (which is essentially what cpanel does)

EDIT: Updated since my_sql is deprecated

Heres a stackoverflow post on how to do it...

[Can I create a database using PDO in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583707/can-i-create-a-database-using-pdo-in-php)

Comment: Same as the answer above me. Don't use `mysql_*` functions. And if I could I'd give you another one for using examples from w3schools. see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Well done, but now your answer does not answer the question, it does not tell how to create users nor how to create databases.

Comment: I was working on it but I'll just link to this one.  I couldn't put something together quick enough.