# Error creating database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wrote this page to receive from a signup page. It redirects, doesn't show any error but phpmyadmin doesn't recognize the database i tried creating, i.e I can't even see the database in phpmyadmin. Whats wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
<?

    $con = mysql_connect_db("localhost", "user", "");
    $create_db = mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE USER', $con);
    if($create_db)
    {
        echo "wored";
    }

    $dbcreate = mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE USER',$con);
    mysql_select_db($dbcreate);

    $create = "CREATE TABLE USER1 (userid INT(20) AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)";

    mysql_query($create);

    $query="INSERT INTO USER1(username,password) VALUES('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]');
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    mysql_close($con);

?>

<?php
    header('location:loginpage.html');
?>
```

Comment: are you using Cpanel to host your site? if so Cpanel doesnt allow you to create databases like that see my answer here for the way to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960630/php-script-automatically-creating-mysql-database/21175022#21175022

Comment: You're making a number of extremely serious mistakes here. Why aren't you using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/)? This would make it a lot harder to trip up over basic things like [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid **severe** [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) caused by recklessly inserting `$_POST` data into queries, not properly hashing user passwords, and using the woefully obsolete `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: In other words "Whats wrong?", pretty much everything. Starting from creating the database and table here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your PHP error logs as what you are trying to do is not even valid PHP so there is no way anything relating your database will work.

First of all, try [mysql_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) instead of mysql_connect_db. Also make sure your database user has the correct privileges (meaning that they can actually create a database).

Also, check your errors with [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), otherwise it will be difficult to know what failed in the database.

Having said that, you should read up on how to submit forms with PHP and its best practices. Creating the user table after submitting the form is definitely not something you want to do. Create your table first and then insert rows into it as the users sign up. Also, you never want to store the user's password. Read up on how to use [Bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) to save user passwords.

Comment: Always use long opening tags <?php instead of short ones <?. Many hosts do not permit MySQL to create the _database_ itself -- you have to do that manually via phpMyAdmin or even the hosting control panel. No need to end PHP and then immediately start it again.

Comment: I now get it. Thanks guys.:)

Answer (score 0):

In your mysql_connect(), you have to use username of mysql. The default username of mysql is 'root'. So the connect should be like this

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
```

I fell your concept is wrong. Each time user comes to your signup page, it comes to this page. So each time the query 'create database user' is run. There is no need to run this query each time. So your first create database. Then retrieve values from signup page.

The php script for create database is:

```
<?php
```

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$query=mysql_query('create database user');
$qu=mysql_query('use user');
if($query)
 {
   echo'Database is created';
 }
  else
 {
   echo'Database is not created';
  }
?>

```
   Now the database 'user' is created.
```