# PHP PDO Create MySQL database and user and grant privileges

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this php function:

```
function createDatabase($dbName,$dbPass) {
         $host = 'localhost';
         $user = 'myuser';
         $user_password = 'mypass';
         $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $user, $user_password);
         $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
         try {
           doLog('Creating Database...');
           $count = $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$dbName`");
           if($count === false) {
             doLog('Could not create database');
             return false;
           }
           doLog('Creating User...');
           $count = $db->exec("CREATE USER '$dbName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbPass'");
           if($count === false) {
             doLog('Could not create user');
             return false;
           }
           doLog('Granting User Privileges...');
           $count = $db->exec("GRANT ALL ON `$dbName`.* TO '$dbName'@'localhost'");
           if($count === false) {
             doLog('Could not grant user privileges');
             return false;
           }
           doLog('Flushing Privileges...');
           $count = $db->exec("FLUSH PRIVILEGES");
           if($count === false) {
             doLog('Could not flush privileges');
             return false;
           }

         } catch (PDOException $e) {
           doLog("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
           return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
```

I was working off another question here:
[Can I create a database using PDO in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583707/can-i-create-a-database-using-pdo-in-php/6549440#6549440)

This code keeps getting hung up during the 3rd query with granting privileges with this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user

The MySQL user in question has global permissions, including grant. What else could I be missing?

Comment: it's the full error message? anything else after `Access denied for user`?

Comment: Yes it lists the user and says for the name of the new database

Comment: What is the username?

Comment: Worked for me after removing \ from doLog('Creating User...'); \

Comment: That slash shouldn't be there, I'll remove it from post.

Answer (score -1):

> The MySQL user in question has global permissions, including grant. What else could I be missing?

Noting but common sense.

If your database says the a user has not permissions **then it is so.**

This is the point of error messages: yo have to read them and fix them. As simple as that.